# c++: can i process std::_Container_base without knowing if it is a map or a vector?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, base-class

guess I have a

```
class C1 : public B { /*...*/ };
class C2 : public B { /*...*/ };

std::map<std::string, C1> myMap;
std::vector<C2> myVector;
```

Is there a way (and what would be the syntax) to call a function foo that…

- just needs to process the functionalities of B
- just needs to process them on all elements of map and vector without caring how they are organized?

`std::vector` and `std::map` are both `std::_Container_base`'s but i have no clue how to write the syntax for (pseudocode):

```
void foo(std::_Container_base-of-Bs)
```

**EDIT**: it's `_Container_base`, not `_Tee`

Comment: I very much doubt that `std::vector` is a `_Tree`...

Comment: 1: Just define a function that takes a `B&`. 2: Define a function template that takes a pair of iterators like the standard library algorithms. You shouldn't be attempting to use `_Tree` / `_Container_base` or anything that starts with `_` + uppercase char, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Can you forget about `_Container_base` for a moment and instead explain what are trying to achieve?

Comment: i dont need a B&, i need a (B[], size) or something like that. Any template would end up with multiple functions, i just want one function

Comment: @user657267 not quite so trivial since the map iterator will return a pair of key and value while vector has only values. Transform iterator from boost would help with that.

Comment: @rhavin you can construct an array of copies of `B` sub-objects using the `B` references which user657267 suggested. If you really want to for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, i could but that sounds really inefficient. Basically, i just want to tell both of them: "gimme a for-each on your items".

Comment: @rhavin which is probably why user657267 suggested you to define a function that takes a `B&` that would be called for each item. Of course, that function could also be a lambda or the code could be inside the template but that would bloat the template needlessly which would be bad since you'll need an instance for each container type that you need.

Comment: The question is not bad, +1 ... i.e. it is reasonable to ask for such.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The below is a survey on the workarounds, whereas the actual question is not answered therein. So here is the answer: I don't know whether *one can process `std::_Container_base` without knowing if it is a map or a vector*.

I couldn't find anything reasonable on the web regarding `std::_Container_base`, and particularly no C++ standard things, so I would guess it stems from a specific compiler implementation.

---

---

`vector` and `map` are completely different storage schemes. I suggest you to not use them generically in the same context. That is, from the first you *could* write a function template

```
template<typename T> foo(T&& t) { /* takes a vector and a map */ }
```

but at least when you access `operator[]`, they'll behave differently. That would be unintuitive and error-prone.

However, this doesn't mean you cannot combine the two approaches -- and abstract on `size()`, `operator[](int)` and possibly other things like some insertion mechanism.

For example, in some recent code of mine, I have `vector`-storage scheme (which uses `std::vector` under the hood), as well as a piecewise constant vector (which uses a `std::map`). If you want to do this, you can derive those two from a common base class

```
template<typename T>
struct ContainerBase
{
    virtual int size() const = 0;
    virtual T operator[](int) const = 0;
    virtual void insert(int, T) = 0;  //if required
};
```

and then set up the required functionality in the derived classes `Vector` and `Map`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
    virtual T operator[](int i) const { return _v[i]; }        
    virtual T size() const { return _v.size(); }        
    // ... insert and so on
    std::vector<T> _v;
};

template<typename T>
struct Map
{
    virtual T operator[](int i) const
    {
       return *std::lower_bound(i);  //add further checks if nothing is found
    }        
    virtual T size() const { return _v.rbegin()->first; // return highest index }        
    // ... insert and so on
    std::map<int, T> _v;
};
```

The `Map` implementation is just a sketch. You should choose some reasonable behaviour for it.

With this, it is easy to set up a function `foo(ContainerBase&)` which works for both `Vector` and `Map`.

Comment: But then I cant use std::map and std::vector anymore, i'd have to use my own classes, right? I just thought, whoever wrote std::map and std::vector would already had thought that someone would need a generic handling. Seems like they dont have any *useful* baseclass wich is rather astonishing because they both are container-lists. :[

Comment: @rhavin: that "useful" base class wouldn't be so useful at all, because there is no way to combine `operator[]`. And a container which offers `size()` only is not very useful.

Comment: yes, not operator[], but size(), **iterator()**, clear() and a couple of other functions.

Comment: @rhavin: that just postpones the problem until the point you want to do something reasonable. `size()` and `clear()` are ok, but the **iterator** returns a completely different thing ... and again you were forced to write *two* instances of your function, one for `std::vector` and one for `std::map`, in order to work with it properly.

Comment: @rhavin: the other answer by Sebastian Riedl is the correct C++ way, but shows the problem: *you have to do further things* in order to handle `vector` and `map` generically (in that case it is conceptually the most straightforward thing: change the behaviour of iterator). **But this shows best why there is no common base class.**

Answer (score 1):

The C++ way is to use templates and iterators.

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void process_bs(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
    std::for_each(first, last, [](B& b) {
        // do something to b here
    });
}
```

For vector, list, deque and set, you can trivially call this using begin and end:

```
process_bs(v.begin(), v.end());
```

For map, the element type is `pair<const Key, Value>`, so you have to adapt the iterators. You can use this with Boost.Range, for example:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
auto values = m | boost::adaptors::map_values;
process_bs(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

To use transparently `B` subclasses into the `foo` function, you can do this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct B{
    int b_member;
};

class C1 : public B { /*...*/ };
class C2 : public B { /*...*/ };

std::map<std::string, C1> myMap;
std::vector<C2> myVector;

// all the magic is into get_B specializations
template<typename E, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, E>::value>::type* a = nullptr>
B& get_B(E& elem)
{
    return elem;
}

template<typename E, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, typename E::second_type>::value>::type* a = nullptr>
B& get_B(E& elem)
{
    return elem.second;
}

// foo can call get_B to hide implementation details of the container
template<typename T>
void foo( T& container)
{
    for(auto& elem : container)
    {
        std::cout << get_B(elem).b_member << '\n';
    }
}


int main()
{
    myVector.resize(10);
    myMap["one"] = {};

    foo(myMap);
    foo(myVector);
}
```

Thanks to SFINAE, `foo` uses the correct specialization of get_B to get a reference to the `B` subclass you want to process.

Comment: this is looking nice :)